# Drupal 7 ubercart product kit of product kits

Tags: drupal, cck, ubercart

I need to create a new content type, it will be contain collection of product kit's.

How can i can create a field, which would contain an existings product kits?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [References Module](http://drupal.org/project/references)